# Person Account record is not accessible to community profile(Guest)

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-community, person-accounts

Step 1: I have created a Lightning Flow where I am accessing a record type(PersonAccount Record Type) and on the next screen, a list of the records under selected RecordType(PersonAccount) is getting populated. This is working properly on run and debug.

Step 2: I am accessing this flow in the Community. I have given permission to "**Run Flows**" and "**Account**" sObject(read and create). I am able to see the first screen(Record Types), but when I select PersonAccount Record, the data is not getting populated in 2nd Screen. 
[**Public can access the community** is enabled -- **I am giving permission to guest Profile**]

The flow is correct, confused about whether there is any permissions issue missing.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think they recently upped the security on guest users accessing some information. I'm not sure of the specifics but you can probably find it in the critical updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the data properly by disabling the checkbox **Secure guest user record access** in **Sharing Settings**.